# How do I solve this kind of 3rd order differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$c_1f'''(x)+c_2 f''(x) + (c_3x + c_4 +c_5x^2)f'(x) + f(x) ( c_6x + c_7 x^3) =0$

Should I use approximation for the third derivative ?

EDIT :- My end result as suggested by @arthur

Assuming

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$

$$c_1a_{n+3}(n+3)(n+2)(n+1) + c_2(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2} + (c_5x^2 -c_4-c_3x)(n+1)a_{n+1}+(c_6x + c_7)a_n =0, n=0,1,2,3..$$

Now how can I proceed forward ?

EDIT: Is this correct, taking n=2 instead of n=0

$$c_1y''' = c_1\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} n(n-1)(n-2)a_n x^{n-3}=c_1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+3)(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+3} x^{n} $$
$$c_2y'' = c_2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}=c_2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}$$
$$c_3xy' =c_3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n}=c_3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n)a_{n}x^{n}$$
$$c_4y' =c_4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n} $$
$$c_5x^2y'  =c_5\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n+1}= c_5\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n}= c_5\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n-1)a_{n-1}x^{n}  + c_5a_{-1}$$
$$c_6xy=c_6\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1}=c_6\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n}= c_6\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n}-c_6a_{-1}$$
$$c_7x^3y=c_7∑_{n=0}^{∞}a_nx^{n+3}=c_7∑_{n=3}^{∞}a_{n-3}x^{n}=c_7∑_{n=0}^{∞}a_{n-3}x^{n}-c_7a_{-3} - c_7a_{-2}x - c_7a_{-1}x^2$$

Comment: No. Use a power series $\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_n x^n$

Comment: @arthur It would be  helpful if you post an answer

Comment: There shouldn't be any $x$ terms in your $a_n$ equation. Equate the coefficients of $x^n$. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series_solution_of_differential_equations

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle f(x)c_6x = c_6 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_n x^{n+1}$ , so when you equate the $x^n$ coefficients take $c_6 a_{n-1}$ from this expression. i.e. What is the coefficient for $x^n$.

Comment: @arthur Is my approach correct now? How to factor them into something useful?:)

Comment: That's closer. $\displaystyle c_1y''' = c_1\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} n(n-1)(n-2)a_n x^{n-3}$. To get $x^n$ substitute $n+3$ for $n$. $\displaystyle c_1y''' = c_1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+3)(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+3} x^{n}$. So the coefficient of $x^n$ is $c_1(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+3}$. Note $n=0$ in the sum.

Comment: $\displaystyle c_3xy' =c_3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n}$ , The coefficient of $x^n$ is $c_3na_n$

Comment: Substitute $n+2$ for $n$. $\displaystyle c_2y'' = c_2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}=c_2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}$.  The coefficient for $x^n$ is $c_2(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}$. If you write out the first three terms in both cases they are $2c_2a_2 + 6c_2a_3x + 12c_2a_4x^2+...$

Comment: I don't know why I don't know why I wrote $a_{n-1}$ instead of $a_{n+1}$. I have also changed the indices of the summation from n= 2 to n=0 but for that I had to subtract the first two terms in some cases.Is that the right way to do it?  It reduces the no. of terms outside the summation  than my previous attempt.

Comment: $\displaystyle c_4y' =c_4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}$

Comment: $\displaystyle c_6xy=c_6\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1}$ : The coefficient of $x^n$ is $c_6a_{n-1}$ , 

$\displaystyle c_7x^3y=c_7\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+3}$ : The coefficient of $x^n$ is $c_7a_{n-3}$ ,

Now add up all the coefficients of $x^n$.

Comment: $\displaystyle f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ , $a_{-1},a_{-2} ...  = 0$ there are no negative powers in this power series. There are differential equations that do use negative powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't read this.
When you do you will realize why no one wanted to answer it.

The method is based on this [tutorial](https://people.richland.edu/james/spring15/m122/projects/ps_solutions.html).

[Maxima:](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)

```
Y:sum(a[n]*x^n,n,0,inf);
Y1:sum(n*a[n]*x^(n-1),n,1,inf);
Y2:sum(n*(n-1)*a[n]*x^(n-2),n,2,inf);
Y3:sum(n*(n-1)*(n-2)*a[n]*x^(n-3),n,3,inf);

E1 : c1*Y3 + c2*Y2 + (c3*x + c4 + c5*x^2)*Y1 + Y*(c6*x + c7*x^3);

E2 : expand(E1);
E3 : intosum(E2);
E4 : factorsum(E3);

E5 : changevar(part(E4,1),k-n-3,k,n)+changevar(part(E4,2)+part(E4,3),k-n-1,k,n)
+changevar(part(E4,4),k-n,k,n)+changevar(part(E4,5),k-n+1,k,n)
+changevar(part(E4,6),k-n+2,k,n)+changevar(part(E4,7),k-n+3,k,n);


E6 : intosum(E5);
E7 : sumcontract(E6);
E8 : factorsum(E7);

Coeffs1 : REC:coeff(part(E8,1,1),x,k);
```

$$Y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{a_{n}\,x^{n}} \tag{1}$$

$$Y1 = \frac{dy}{dx} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }{n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-1}} \tag{2}$$

$$Y2 = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty }{\left(n-1\right)\,n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-2}} \tag{3}$$

$$Y3 =  \frac{d^3y}{dx^3} =\sum_{n=3}^{\infty }{\left(n-2\right)\,\left(n-1\right)\,n\,a_{n}\,
 x^{n-3}} \tag{4}$$

The equation $c_1f'''(x)+c_2 f''(x) + (c_3x + c_4 +c_5x^2)f'(x) + f(x) ( c_6x + c_7 x^3) =0$

$$E1 = \left({\it c_7}\,x^3+{\it c_6}\,x\right)\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{a_{n
 }\,x^{n}}+\left({\it c_5}\,x^2+{\it c_3}\,x+{\it c_4}\right)\,\sum_{
 n=1}^{\infty }{n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-1}}+{\it c_2}\,\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }{
 \left(n-1\right)\,n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-2}}+{\it c_1}\,\sum_{n=3}^{\infty 
 }{\left(n-2\right)\,\left(n-1\right)\,n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-3}} \tag{5}$$

Expansion of terms:

$$E2 = {\it c_7}\,x^3\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{a_{n}\,x^{n}}+{\it c_6}\,x\,
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{a_{n}\,x^{n}}+{\it c_5}\,x^2\,\sum_{n=1}^{
 \infty }{n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-1}}+{\it c_3}\,x\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }{n\,a
 _{n}\,x^{n-1}}+{\it c_4}\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }{n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-1}}+
 {\it c_2}\,\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }{\left(n^2\,a_{n}\,x^{n-2}-n\,a_{n}\,
 x^{n-2}\right)}+{\it c_1}\,\sum_{n=3}^{\infty }{\left(n^3\,a_{n}\,x
 ^{n-3}-3\,n^2\,a_{n}\,x^{n-3}+2\,n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-3}\right)} \tag{6}$$

Move the $x$ multipliers into the sums.

$$E3 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{{\it c_7}\,a_{n}\,x^{n+3}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty 
 }{{\it c_5}\,n\,a_{n}\,x^{n+1}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{{\it c_6}\,a_{n
 }\,x^{n+1}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }{{\it c_3}\,n\,a_{n}\,x^{n}}+\sum_{n=
 1}^{\infty }{{\it c_4}\,n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-1}}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }{
 {\it c_2}\,\left(n^2\,a_{n}\,x^{n-2}-n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-2}\right)}+
 \sum_{n=3}^{\infty }{{\it c_1}\,\left(n^3\,a_{n}\,x^{n-3}-3\,n^2\,a
 _{n}\,x^{n-3}+2\,n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-3}\right)} \tag{7}$$

Collect factors:

$$E4 = {\it c_7}\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{a_{n}\,x^{n+3}}+{\it c_5}\,\sum_{n=
 1}^{\infty }{n\,a_{n}\,x^{n+1}}+{\it c_6}\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{a_{n
 }\,x^{n+1}}+{\it c_3}\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }{n\,a_{n}\,x^{n}}+
 {\it c_4}\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }{n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-1}}+{\it c_2}\,\sum_{
 n=2}^{\infty }{\left(n-1\right)\,n\,a_{n}\,x^{n-2}}+{\it c_1}\,
 \sum_{n=3}^{\infty }{n\,\left(n^2-3\,n+2\right)\,a_{n}\,x^{n-3}} \tag{8}$$

Set all powers to $x^k$:

$$E5 = {\it c_1}\,\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }{\left(k^3+6\,k^2+11\,k+6\right)\,a
 _{k+3}\,x^{k}}+{\it c_2}\,\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }{\left(k^2+3\,k+2
 \right)\,a_{k+2}\,x^{k}}+{\it c_4}\,\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }{\left(k+1
 \right)\,a_{k+1}\,x^{k}}+{\it c_3}\,\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }{k\,a_{k}\,x
 ^{k}}+{\it c_5}\,\sum_{k=2}^{\infty }{\left(k-1\right)\,a_{k-1}\,x^{
 k}}+{\it c_6}\,\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }{a_{k-1}\,x^{k}}+{\it c_7}\,
 \sum_{k=3}^{\infty }{a_{k-3}\,x^{k}}  \tag{9}$$

Move the $c_k$ multipliers into the sums:

$$E6 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty }{{\it c_1}\,\left(k^3+6\,k^2+11\,k+6\right)\,a
 _{k+3}\,x^{k}}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }{{\it c_2}\,\left(k^2+3\,k+2
 \right)\,a_{k+2}\,x^{k}}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }{{\it c_4}\,\left(k+1
 \right)\,a_{k+1}\,x^{k}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }{{\it c_3}\,k\,a_{k}\,x
 ^{k}}+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty }{{\it c_5}\,\left(k-1\right)\,a_{k-1}\,x^{
 k}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }{{\it c_6}\,a_{k-1}\,x^{k}}+\sum_{k=3}^{
 \infty }{{\it c_7}\,a_{k-3}\,x^{k}}  \tag{10}$$

Collect like terms:

$$E7 = \sum_{k=3}^{\infty }{\left({\it c_1}\,\left(k^3+6\,k^2+11\,k+6
 \right)\,a_{k+3}\,x^{k}+{\it c_2}\,\left(k^2+3\,k+2\right)\,a_{k+2}
 \,x^{k}+{\it c_4}\,\left(k+1\right)\,a_{k+1}\,x^{k}+{\it c_3}\,k\,a
 _{k}\,x^{k}+{\it c_5}\,\left(k-1\right)\,a_{k-1}\,x^{k}+{\it c_6}\,a
 _{k-1}\,x^{k}+{\it c_7}\,a_{k-3}\,x^{k}\right)}+a_{1}\,{\it c_6}\,x^
 2+a_{1}\,{\it c_5}\,x^2+3\,a_{3}\,{\it c_4}\,x^2+2\,a_{2}\,{\it c_3}
 \,x^2+12\,a_{4}\,{\it c_2}\,x^2+60\,a_{5}\,{\it c_1}\,x^2+a_{0}\,
 {\it c_6}\,x+2\,a_{2}\,{\it c_4}\,x+a_{1}\,{\it c_3}\,x+6\,a_{3}\,
 {\it c_2}\,x+24\,a_{4}\,{\it c_1}\,x+a_{1}\,{\it c_4}+2\,a_{2}\,
 {\it c_2}+6\,a_{3}\,{\it c_1}  \tag{11}$$

Collect coefficients of $x^k$.

$E8$ collects all the $x^k$ coefficients inside the sum and all the stray terms outside of it.

Note: $k$  starts from $3$.

$$E8 : \sum_{k=3}^{\infty }{\left(\left({\it c_1}\,k^3+6\,{\it c_1}\,k^2+
 11\,{\it c_1}\,k+6\,{\it c_1}\right)\,a_{k+3}+\left({\it c_2}\,k^2+3
 \,{\it c_2}\,k+2\,{\it c_2}\right)\,a_{k+2}+\left({\it c_4}\,k+
 {\it c_4}\right)\,a_{k+1}+{\it c_3}\,k\,a_{k}+\left({\it c_5}\,k+
 {\it c_6}-{\it c_5}\right)\,a_{k-1}+{\it c_7}\,a_{k-3}\right)\,x^{k}
 }+a_{1}\,{\it c_6}\,x^2+a_{1}\,{\it c_5}\,x^2+3\,a_{3}\,{\it c_4}\,x
 ^2+2\,a_{2}\,{\it c_3}\,x^2+12\,a_{4}\,{\it c_2}\,x^2+60\,a_{5}\,
 {\it c_1}\,x^2+6\,{\it c_1}\,\left(4\,a_{4}\,x+a_{3}\right)+2\,
 {\it c_2}\,\left(3\,a_{3}\,x+a_{2}\right)+a_{0}\,{\it c_6}\,x+2\,a_{
 2}\,{\it c_4}\,x+a_{1}\,{\it c_3}\,x+a_{1}\,{\it c_4} = 0 \tag{12}$$

coefficients of $x^k$:

$$Coeffs1 : \left({\it c_1}\,k^3+6\,{\it c_1}\,k^2+11\,{\it c_1}\,k+6\,
 {\it c_1}\right)\,a_{k+3}+\left({\it c_2}\,k^2+3\,{\it c_2}\,k+2\,
 {\it c_2}\right)\,a_{k+2}+\left({\it c_4}\,k+{\it c_4}\right)\,a_{k+
 1}+{\it c_3}\,k\,a_{k}+\left({\it c_5}\,k+{\it c_6}-{\it c_5}\right)
 \,a_{k-1}+{\it c_7}\,a_{k-3}  \tag{13} = 0$$

From $E8$ collect all the coefficients of $x^k$ for $k=0..2$:

$$ 6 c_1 a_{3} +2 c_2 a_{2} +a_1 c_4 = 0 $$

$$ 24c_1a_4 + 3a_2 + a_0c_6 + 2a_2c_4 + a_1c_3 = 0 $$

$$ a_1c_6 + a_1c_5 + 3a_2c_4 + 2a_2c_3 + 12a_4c_2 + 60a_5c_1 = 0$$

$a_0$..$a_5$ need to be chosen to satisfy these equations. There could be arbitrarily many solutions.

The other coefficients $a_6$... can be calculated from $Coeffs1$ equation $(13)$

At this point we need to be reminded that $\displaystyle Y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{a_{n}\,x^{n}} $