# How to solve a system of equations with symbolic dimension computationally?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, python, computer-algebra-systems

Suppose I have a vector of unknowns $x_i$, with $i=1,...,N$, where $N$ is symbolic, and I have some nonlinear system of $M$ equations, $$f_m(x_1,...,x_N) = 0\quad \forall m,$$ with $f_m: \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the family of (possibly nonlinear) equations in this system. How should I approach this problem with Sympy?

To make things more concrete and simple, suppose I have the system $$x_i+\sum_{j=1}^Nx_j^2 = 0, \forall i$$

I could describe this typical equation in Sympy as follows:

```
N = Symbol('N', integer = True)
i = Idx('i', (1,N))
j = Idx('j', (1,N))
x = IndexedBase('x')
eq = x[i] + Sum(x[j]**2, j) # This is a generic equation, valid for all i
```

How to state this problem to the computer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the example $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^Nx_j^2$ is common to all equations so $x_i = x_k$ for all $i,k  \in \{i\}$.

Comment: @arthur True, but notice the question is more general and that was just a simple example. I am looking for a computational approach that minimizes the manual work of trying to notice these kinds of patterns that you just pointed out, instead leaving it to the computer.

Comment: When the computers start to think the humans will stop.

Comment: @arthur I agree generally, but the issue here is that my problem involves a large family for first-order conditions, and trying to solve it manually may lead to human errors that are difficult to detect. Ideally, I would like to try to solve it in the computer to correct these possible errors and to find patterns (like the one you pointed out) that could simplify the problem but that we, as a human, may not see easily (since it may involve many equations) :).

Comment: I use Maxima. See my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182490/help-in-solving-nonlinear-system-of-equations/4182569#4182569

Comment: @arthur Unfortunately, this is not the kind of problem I am trying to solve here. In your problem you have six unknowns and six equations, with is pretty straightforward. In my problem, I have an symbolic number of unknowns ($M_U$) and a symbolic number of equations ($M_E$). That is, it is a *family* of equations and unknowns. Ideally, I would like to have an expression of $x_i$ contingent on $M_U$, the parameters, etc. Does it make sense? Perhaps I should make that clearer in the question.

Comment: ok: Maxima does support an array of unknowns. Note  a[n] with infinite n, this can be bound see  Y:sum(a[n]*x^n,n,0,inf); in   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748359/how-do-i-solve-this-kind-of-3rd-order-differential-equation/3749834#3749834

Comment: @arthur I am not familiar with Maxima, but it seems to me that you are using an array of unknowns inside an infinite series. But I don't see how it solves the problem posed in the question.

Comment: econbernardo - I experimented with sums in Maxima and it failed to do some simple operations. So I wouldn't recommend it for what you are trying to do.

Comment: econbernardo - I also did a crash course in sympy and couldn't see how to do it either.

Comment: @arthur Me neither... I am thinking that maybe the approach would be to use functions instead of indexed symbols, and then solve a functional equation?